# How can i clear the memory after converting BitmapImage to Byte

Tags: c#, memory, out-of-memory

I have two functions: one to convert from image to byte and other to convert from byte to bitmapImage.
So, when I open the window with that images, I convert from byte to bitmapImage and it works great, but when I close and open it again it just keeps on memory and if I continue to do that time and time again it just throws an exception `Out Of Memory exception`

Image to byte->

```cs
       private byte[] ConvertImageToBinary(Image img)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ss = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ss, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                var s = ss.ToArray();
                var jpegQuality = 50;
                Image image;
                using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(s))
                {
                    image = Image.FromStream(inputStream);
                    var jpegEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()
                      .First(c => c.FormatID == System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                    var encoderParameters = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
                    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, jpegQuality);
                    Byte[] outputBytes;
                    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        image.Save(outputStream, jpegEncoder, encoderParameters);
                        return outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Byte to bitmap ->

```cs
 public BitmapImage ConvertBinaryToImage(byte[] array)
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(array))
            {
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; // here
                image.StreamSource = ms;
                image.EndInit();
                image.Freeze();
            }
            return image;
        }
```

[image: Memory Usage]

When I open the WindowDragAndDrop it loads all the images
[image]

But when I close it it still uses the same amount of memory
[image]

Comment: Did you try `GC.Collect`, if it does not help you aren't disposing all your objects or at least hold references onto them? Also do you use the same window instance again?

Comment: Yes, It's the same window instance, I close it and open it again collecting data from db.

Comment: The using statement should automatically dispose which release the memory.  The return memory has to be handle in the parent code.

Comment: Does the "Image" class require disposing? | Actually, wich Image class is that? There are several.

Answer (score 0):

Image is indeed disposable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8), so you also need:

```
using (var image = Image.FromStream(inputStream)){

}
```

Around everywhere you use Image objects.

Comment: Does the BitmapImage is disposable?

Comment: doesn't look like it no (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=netframework-4.8)